Building libshout using cmake
I'm trying to build libshout for Android using cmake.
I do this in my high level CMakeLists.txt:
FetchContent_Declare(
        ogg
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/xiph/ogg.git
        GIT_TAG v1.3.5
        FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS
)

FetchContent_Declare(
        vorbis
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/xiph/vorbis.git
        GIT_TAG v1.3.7
        FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ogg)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(vorbis)

add_subdirectory(third_party/shout)

I get this error
CMake Error at third_party/shout/CMakeLists.txt:41 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "shout" links to:

    Vorbis::vorbis

The line to which the above corresponds are
find_package(Vorbis REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(shout PRIVATE Vorbis::vorbis Vorbis::vorbisenc Vorbis::vorbisfile)

so it seems that find_package works fine but the targets can not get found for some reason.
I'm new to CMake, could you guys point me out to what I'm doing wrong here?
UPDATE:
After changing FetchContent_Declare's first arg to vrbs(changed in FetchContent_MakeAvailable as well) I'm getting:
CMake Error at /snap/cmake/1399/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Vorbis (missing: VORBIS_INCLUDE_DIRS VORBIS_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/cmake/1399/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  third_party/shout/cmake/FindVorbis.cmake:19 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  third_party/shout/CMakeLists.txt:40 (find_package)



It depends on script third_party/shout/cmake/FindVorbis.cmake which targets will be created during find_package(Vorbis).

@Tsyvarev it does. But I suppose targets will be created during FetchContent_MakeAvailable. Isn't it?

FetchContent_MakeAvailable just executes the subproject's code. In version 1.3.7 Vorbis doesn't create aliases like Vorbis::vorbis: https://github.com/xiph/vorbis/blob/v1.3.7/lib/CMakeLists.txt. (But in master branch aliases are created: https://github.com/xiph/vorbis/blob/master/lib/CMakeLists.txt#L81).
